# Text input and column width change for multiple cell and columns respectively at once

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I want know the shorten the code for inserting multiple texts to cells and reducing width of column at once. So, is there a way to do that.

```
Columns("A:A").ColumnWidth = 2
Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("C:C").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("D:D").ColumnWidth = 15
Columns("E:E").ColumnWidth = 10
Columns("F:F").ColumnWidth = 10
```

and for this:

```
Range("A2").Value = "first name"
Range("A3").Value = "surname"
Range("B2").Value = "Level"
Range("C2").Value = "Score"
Range("C3").Value = "in percentage"
Range("D2").Value = "Status"
Range("D3").Value = "pass/fail"
Range("E2").Value = "Rank"
Range("F2").Value = "Remarks"
```

Is there a way to solve this in a single line instead of doing it for every single line one at a time. Or this is the only way?

I am expecting something like:

```
Range("E2,E3,F2,......").Value = "........."
Columns("A:A,B:B,C:C.....").ColumnWidth = 10
```

But I know the above does not work. If there is a shorter way then I am up for it. If not, this is also simple. It is just long.

*P.S. I found these references but they are not really what I expected.

1. [Separate cell content after "-" for multiple columns at once](https://superuser.com/questions/720186/separate-cell-content-after-for-multiple-columns-at-once)
2. [Set Width of Multiple Column in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/605662/set-width-of-multiple-column-in-excel)*

Comment: your command should be written like this, **Range("D:D,F:F,H:H").ColumnWidth = 4**  or even this one also works **Union(Columns("D"), Columns("F"), Columns("H")).ColumnWidth = 4**

Comment: If you want to enter SINGLE Value in many Cells then Try this,                     **Range("E3:G3,I3:K3,M3:O3,Q3").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "All"**

Comment: Thanks for the column width instruction. Helps to trim down many lines. But for the cell value, I tried this one but it does not seem to work:
`Range("E3:H3").Select`
`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "N"`

Comment: Okay U try this it's working I've tested right now, **ActiveSheet.Range("A106,B106,C104:D106").Value = "SomeValue"** or **ActiveSheet.Range("A104:D106").Value = "SomeValue"**

Comment: Little update in previous command & will work also, **Range("A104:A106").Select**   ,,,,,,                                                                                  
**Selection.value = "Noo"**

Comment: @RajeshS thank you for the command. This is much better.